# How to change the selected cell color

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an application in which data are comes from server after parsing, and showing these data like Heading, title and image in custom `tableview` cell which are having cell image [gradient image] and these image are dynamically generated. I want to change the image background color [orange color] after selecting for navigate to another `viewcontroller` class.

Answer (score 2):

Hii,

use

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

for Image :

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];

UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
    ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = img;
```

for Color :

```
cell.selectedTextColor = [UIColor yourcolor]
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method

**Edit:**
you can do

```
CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
```

or what ever with that cell.

Comment: I would overwrite the - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated method of the table view cell for this...

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is:

```
UIView *view = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 , cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height]);
view.backgroundColor = ....;

cell.selectedBackgroundView = view;
```